# Multithreading java server and android client app socket communication with user sign in system

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a Android game app which communicates with a desktop Java server.

I have already established communication between devices and server and it worked properly (tried it locally through router). I don't have a problem implementing the game.

My main screen has fields for the user to log in to my game or create a new user. The server is multithreading and when a user connects to it, it starts a new thread if user exists and username and password match with one of the users already registered. A message is shown at the device and the user successfully logs in.

The next activity consists of info about the user (username, level, wins/loses etc) and has two buttons (log out and new game). Pressing new game should search for another (random) logged in player who pressed the same button and start a game between those two. And if I start a new thread (Game thread) I won't be able to see both clients. So my question is how am I supposed to connect the two clients (through the server) and let them play? Any ideas or articles would really help.

Comment: have you googled for game networking or something?? there´re tons of solutions. On books, the first one from the Game Programming Gems tackles the networking thing from begin to masters ^g^

Comment: I googled a lot but i did not find anything that has to do with my aproach.So if you have any link that can help i would appreciate it.

Comment: No, man, nothing to do with your approach... But *maybe* it is the time for a research, even when it is a little late already

Comment: Ok i'll search more and try a few things.But if anyone else know something about this please post.